# How to get values from string with split in java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string having key and value:

```
A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5
```

I need a split regex in java to get these values **(1,2,3,4,5)** from above string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with this pattern **[0-9]+**

## Example:

```
    String toIndex = "A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(toIndex);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

and in the while instead of printing the groups add then to a list or similar for latter manipulation

Comment: Thanks @Xoce,
There may be string in place of integer. So what regex i should use.
`A=AA,B=BB,C=CC,D=DD,E=EE`

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
    String s = "A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=(\\d+)");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

\d+ is for one until n digits

Comment: Thanks @Jens, There may be string in place of integer. So what regex i should use.

Fg: `A=AA,B=BB,C=CC,D=DD,E=EE`

Comment: @VarunArya use \\w+ instead of \\d+

Comment: Yup (y). 
One more question why Xoce rate it to negetive??

Comment: @VarunArya I do not know. ask him

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked to use split, this will work as well.

```
    String str2 = "A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5";
    String [] between = str2.split("=+|,");
    for(int i=1; i<between.length; i+=2){
        System.out.println(between[i]);
    }
```

Works for both strings and numbers between = and ,

(A=AA,B=BB,C=CC,D=DD,E=EE)

Comment: That is the one. I want.. Thanks a lot @jsurf :)

Comment: Anytime @VarunArya